# C# - Use a referenced library from an included project

Tags: c#, include, project, libraries

for my C# projects, I created a "Helper-Project" that handles some common issues, which I use in my other projects. For the specific solution, I include my "Helper-Project" and use the public classes defined within.

In my "Helper-Project", I referenced some external libraries, which I want to use in my specific working-project (that includes the "Helper-Project") as well. Is there a way to access those referenced libraries of the "Helper-Project" from the "Working-Project" as well, or do I have to include them in the "Working-Project" as well?

Here is schematic display of the structure:

```
solution
  working-project
  helper-project
    references
      library-that-I-want-to-use-in-working-project-as-well
```

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to reference them in the working project.

If for some reason you absolutely cannot reference those libraries in the working project and the methods you need from the libraries are few, you can (but shouldn't) create wrapper methods in the helper project:

```
string wrapperMethod() {
    return libraryMethod();
}
```

Comment: I have referenced it in my working project and deployed the program. Luckily the deployed dlls are not doubled (I feared: one for the helper-project, one for the working-project) so it should be no problem to reference them twice :)